# Django navbar links disappearing in the post

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

So sorry probably this is very easy but i learn django and have a problem. My navbar working on index page is perfectly. but when i go contact form or another post url, navbar links disappear.

When i go some post page or my contact form page

1-  {{ article.title }} and href links are disappear

Can i ask help ?

my navbar.html

```
{% load i18n %}

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu-wrapper center-relative">
            <nav id="header-main-menu">
                <div class="mob-menu">Menu</div>
                <ul class="main-menu sm sm-clean">
                    <li><a href="{% url "index" %}">{% trans "HomePage" %}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">{% trans "Services" %}</a></li>
                    <li>
                       {% for article in articles %}
                        {% if article.slug == 'about_us' %}
                        <a href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}">
                            {{ article.title }}</a>

                        {% endif %}
                       {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#video">{% trans "HELLO WORLD" %}</a></li>



                  <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1643 dropdown">
        <a title="" href="">{% trans "Producs" %}</a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1644 dropdown">
        <a title="Level 2" href="">{% trans "Consult" %}</a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li  >
        {% for category in category %}
    {% if category.name == 'consult' %}
       {% for article in category.get_article %}
          <a title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}"> <p> {{ article.title }}</p></a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}</li>

</ul>
</li>
<li>

    {% for category in category %}
    {% if category.name == 'header' %}
       {% for article in category.get_article %}
          <a title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}"> <p> {{ article.title }}</p></a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


</li>

</ul>
</li>


<li><a href="{% url 'contact_form' %}">{% trans "İletişim" %}</a></li>


                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

article/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,  get_object_or_404
from .models import Article, Category
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

# Create your views here.

def articles(request):
    keyword = request.GET.get("keyword")
    if keyword:
        articles = Article.objects.filter(title__contains=keyword)
        paginator = Paginator(articles, 1)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        articles = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request,"articles.html",{"articles":articles})


    articles = Article.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(articles, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    articles = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render(request, "articles.html", {"articles":articles})

def index(request): 
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        "articles": articles,
        "category": category,

         }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def detail(request,slug):
    # article = Article.objects.filter (id = id).first()
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug = slug)
    category = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, "detail.html", {"article":article, "category":category,})



def category_detail(request,slug):
    template = "category_detail.html"

    category=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
    article=Article.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'category' : category,
        'article' : article,
    }
    return render(request,template,context)

def category_page(request):
    object_list = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': object_list,}
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

contact_form/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .forms import ContactForm

try:
    from django.urls import reverse
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # pragma: no cover


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    recipient_list = None
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):

        if self.recipient_list is not None:
            kwargs.update({'recipient_list': self.recipient_list})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('contact_form_sent')
```

Comment: We need to see your views code as well.

Comment: @JonahBishop thank you so much for intresting. i added article/views.py and contact_form/views.py...

Comment: i found the solution; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296759/django-navbar-content-links-are-disappear thanks