# Django navbar content links are disappear

Tags: django, python-3.x

Im stuck my django blog project.

I create a standart blog but i have a problem now. When i add in navbar some categorys in all post i see this post index page. But when i go another page (like contact form) navbar post links are disappear.

let me explain;
i create three article and i add this articles in "Music" category

after then i use this code in my navbar;

```
 {% for category in category %}
    {% if category.name == 'Music' %}
       {% for article in category.get_article %}
          <li class="nav-item" > <a class="nav-link" title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}"> <p> {{ article.title }}</p></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So I want to do here is to bring the titles of the articles in the music category to the menu. I'm not sure if this is the right method but it works on the index page.

After this if i go contact page this links are disappear. (Also Contact form is a separate app https://github.com/maru/django-contact-form-recaptcha.)

same time, I use another method but these links are also disappear;

```
{% for article in articles %}
    {% if article.slug == 'about_us' %}
       <a href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}">
            {{ article.title }}</a>

     {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
```

Why disappear this links? How can i solve this? Can i ask help ?

my navbar.html

```
{% load i18n %}

        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class="menu-wrapper center-relative">
            <nav id="header-main-menu">
                <div class="mob-menu">Menu</div>
                <ul class="main-menu sm sm-clean">
                    <li><a href="{% url "index" %}">{% trans "HomePage" %}</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">{% trans "Services" %}</a></li>
                    <li>
                       {% for article in articles %}
                        {% if article.slug == 'about_us' %}
                        <a href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}">
                            {{ article.title }}</a>

                        {% endif %}
                       {% endfor %}
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#video">{% trans "HELLO WORLD" %}</a></li>



                  <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1643 dropdown">
        <a title="" href="">{% trans "Producs" %}</a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1644 dropdown">
        <a title="Level 2" href="">{% trans "Consult" %}</a>
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
<li  >
        {% for category in category %}
    {% if category.name == 'music' %}
       {% for article in category.get_article %}
          <a title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}"> <p> {{ article.title }}</p></a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}</li>

</ul>
</li>
<li>

    {% for category in category %}
    {% if category.name == 'header' %}
       {% for article in category.get_article %}
          <a title="{{ article.title }}" href="{% url 'article:detail' slug=article.slug %}"> <p> {{ article.title }}</p></a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


</li>

</ul>
</li>


<li><a href="{% url 'contact_form' %}">{% trans "İletişim" %}</a></li>


                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

article/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,  get_object_or_404
from .models import Article, Category
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

# Create your views here.


def index(request): 
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        "articles": articles,
        "category": category,

         }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)

def detail(request,slug):
    # article = Article.objects.filter (id = id).first()
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug = slug)
    category = Category.objects.all()

    return render(request, "detail.html", {"article":article, "category":category,})



def category_detail(request,slug):
    template = "category_detail.html"

    category=get_object_or_404(Category,slug=slug)
    article=Article.objects.filter(category=category)

    context = {
        'category' : category,
        'article' : article,
    }
    return render(request,template,context)

def category_page(request):
    object_list = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'object_list': object_list,}
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

contact_form/views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

from .forms import ContactForm

try:
    from django.urls import reverse
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse  # pragma: no cover


class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    recipient_list = None
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):

        if self.recipient_list is not None:
            kwargs.update({'recipient_list': self.recipient_list})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):

        return reverse('contact_form_sent')
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: You've only added `articles` and `category` (btw I would rename that to `categories`) to the context used to render the `index` view, not the context of the other views. So for the other views, such as the `ContactFormView`, `articles` and `category` are undefined and won't render in your template.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks for answer? Is there an easy way to do this? Can I use it all in one place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @dirkgroten has mentioned, views manage context only on pages served by that view.

To have the same items everywhere across pages served by different views, you could use a [context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

You can basically take the code you have in `index`, make it return `context` instead of render and put its path to `context_processors` of `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py`.
Context processors are loaded with every request and the items from their returned dictionaries are automatically included in the context.

As a best practice, it's better to keep your context processors in a separate file.

Example `context_processors.py` which can be placed in the same directory as your `views.py` and `models.py`:

```
from .models import Article, Category

def navigation(request): 
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()

    return {
        "articles": articles,
        "category": category,
     }
```

In `settings.py` find `TEMPLATES` option, which probably looks something like
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Add `'APP_NAME.context_processors.navigation'`, after `'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',`

Replace `APP_NAME` with the name of the directory where your files are located.

Comment: thank you so much for answer. Can you explain to me by writing the code? where do I need to add code? I'm so new django, so sorry for this.

Comment: I've added an example